# Scaling objects without scaling children

Tags: objects, scale

I have two basic meshes: "head", selected, and "tube", below (apologies for the bad layout).

[image: 1]

What I'm trying to do is extend the tube object by scaling it in the z-axis, while keeping the head in the same size and same place relative to it. Obviously, just scaling the tube will have no effect on the head, while using Proportional Editing also scales the head. If I just scale tube then move head to it, it's difficult to get the placement precise (since vertex co-ordinates aren't the same between objects).

How do I scale one and keep the other fixed relative to it?

Full disclosure: this is just a simplified example, while my actual mesh is imported from a .obj, so any solutions involving creating the mesh from scratch won't work.

Comment: Did you try moving the pivot point of the cylinder to the top? that way when you scale in Z it extends downwards without intersecting the "head"

Comment: I think you could make a selection of top vertex (loop select) and move it up.

Comment: @SamirRahamtalla This worked perfectly, thank you. I thought I didn't need to do it because the mesh I was using had "heads" at both ends, before I realised I was working on the wrong mesh.

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to do what you've described. It's kind of difficult to know which method will suit your particular project. But I will offer some ideas.

### Method 1.

**Parent each object to the bones of a two-bone Armature. Then set the child bone to not inherit scale.**

### Method 2.

**Use Vertex Parenting to parent the upper object to the vertices of the top part of the lower object.**

### Method 3.

**Join them as a single object, then create a Shape Key wherein the bottom part is taller but the top part is simply raised (not scaled).**

### Method 4.

**Just move them (super-basic).**

If this doesn't need to animate, then it's as simple as grabbing the upper object, translating it up on the Z axis by some value (you can type it in), and then going into Edit Mode and doing the same for just the vertices on the upper part of the lower object.

Vertex Snapping is also a handy tool for this kind of situation, because you can snap the lower object's vertices to the bottom of the upper object.

As I stated in the beginning, there are so many ways to do this, plus I don't know your skill level or the details of what you are aiming to do, so it's hard to know how to answer. But I hope this helps. Feel free to ask questions.

Comment: I would say vertex parent is the best of these options.

Answer (score 5):

If parenting the head works for transforms other than scale, you can use a [ChildOf constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/constraints/relationship/child_of.html). This constraint allows you to turn off the scaling influence of the parenting.

[image: child of constraint]

The thing with scaling the parent on the z-axis is that the child will not move up with the top of the mesh. You can get around this by positioning the object origin at the top of the parent, this makes scaling happen away from that point so the child stays on the top edge. Another option is to use a [Shrinkwrap constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/constraints/relationship/shrinkwrap.html), this will move the head down against the cylinder (the head origin needs to be at the base of the mesh) but has limits on the distance it will move upwards, so may not work fully.

Where you mention having trouble re-positioning the head on the parent object, you may want to try [snapping](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html) to align the two surfaces.

Comment: Nice one! The constraint method hadn't occurred to me. I like it.